# Can't add field to ModelForm at __init__

Tags: python, django, modelform

I have a problem with `ModelForm`. Field `test1` is displayed, but `test2`- is not. Playing with `base_fields` didn't help.

```
# models.py
class Country(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

# admin.py
class CountryAdminForm(ModelForm):
    test1 = forms.CharField('test1')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CountryAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['test2'] = forms.CharField('test2')

    class Meta:
        model = Country

class CountryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = CountryAdminForm

admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Solved!

```
class CountryAdminForm(ModelForm):
    test1 = forms.CharField('test1')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CountryAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['test2'] = forms.CharField('test2')
        self.Meta.fields.append('test2')

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ['name', 'test1',]
```

...

Comment: should they all be test1 rather than some of them being test2?

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't use **self.Meta.fields.append** in Django 1.4, because the **fields** in question is a tuple. You have to concatenate with **self.Meta.fields += ('another_field',)** instead, for example.

Comment: I have this same problem, but the solution doesn't work with Django 1.5. Could you help me, please ?